# Application startup status in Websphere

Tags: java, tomcat, websphere, ejb-3.0, servletcontextlistener

I have a web application deployed in Websphere. At server startup, I am trying to load some values from database through ServletContextListener. If any exception occurs at that time, I want the web application start up status as failed.

In order to achieve this, I am throwing a Runtime exception from ServletContextListener. This is working fine on Tomcat as it is not starting the webapp. But, on Websphere, the application start up status is showing as Success.

Please let me know the way to handle this for a normal webapp, which does not use EJBs.

Comment: Which version of WebSphere Application Server?  Are you using full profile or the Liberty profile?  Are you on the latest fixpak?

Comment: I am using WAS version 8.5.5.8

Answer (score 0):

The section [Application Status](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/urun_rtargetmap.html) list all avaiable status. You can notice there is no `fail` or something like that.
Websphere does not support the behavior that you expected in 8.x or older version.

There is a discussion : [Stop application on servlet initialization failure](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=98644673-0380-4ed7-9d41-3bb6356bf6a4).
It mention a possible solution but the customize implementation is not released yet.

Comment: By fail, I mean to say it shows a cross-mark for applications which did not start properly. It show a tick for apps which started correctly. I just wanted to show that status when I am throwing an exception from ServletContextListener. However, Websphere is catching that and dealing with it and starting the app as normal.